# How do I make Edge stop with white screen flashes?

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge, dark-mode

I have a feeling that most users have seen the white blank screen appear in a browser before it renders anything and I am wondering how I set it to be black to make it less harsh on the eyes when jumping between two dark pages.